# attachment propriety not working in ionic local notification plugin

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native, localnotification

We are working on hybrid mobile application (ionic 3 and angular 4). We are trying attachment with local-notification.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/local-notifications/

we tried like this

```
this.localNotifications.schedule({
      id: 1,
      title: 'Title',
      text: 'Dec',
      attachments: ['https://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/golden-soccer-ball-3yLR9z1-600.jpg'],
      foreground: true,
      vibrate: true,
      actions: [
        { id: 'yes', title: 'Yes' },
        { id: 'no',  title: 'No' }
    ]
    });
```

unable to  get attachment in notification .Let us know what we missed .

Answer (score 0):

pass small images

```
uri='https://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/golden-soccer-ball-3yLR9z1-600.jpg'

this.localNotifications.schedule({
      id: 1,
      title: 'Title',
      text: 'Dec',
      attachments: [uri],
      foreground: true,
      vibrate: true,
      actions: [
        { id: 'yes', title: 'Yes' },
        { id: 'no',  title: 'No' }
    ]
    });
```